# Finding the solutions of $i$. In particular, finding the roots

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was asked to compute the 8-th roots of $i$.

Correct me if I am wrong, but am I looking for 8 different solutions to this? My thought was to first consider a root of the form $cos(x) + i sin(x)$. So, we are dealing with $cos(8x) + isin(8x)$. At this point I believe the $cos(8x)$ is $1$. Therefore we have $1 + isin(8x)$, so we want to solve $sin(8x) = -1$. At this point, I go blank. I am not sure if my logic on doing this problem is correct either, so check if I am wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Use $i=e^{i\pi/2+i2\pi n}$ to get $8$ solutions
$$
(i)^{1/8}=e^{i(\pi/2+2\pi n)/8}=e^{i(\pi/16+n\pi/4 )},
$$
where $n$ runs from $0$ to $7$.

Answer (score 3):

You started off okay, in assuming that an eighth root of $i$ has form $\cos x+i\sin x,$ from which we can indeed conclude that its eighth power is $\cos(8x)+i\sin(8x).$ However, its eighth power should be $i$, not $1$, so we need $x$ to satisfy $\cos(8x)=0$ and $\sin(8x)=1.$ We need only solve $\sin(8x)=1$. Do you know how to find the general solution to $\sin u=1$? If not, hover your cursor over the spoiler-prevention box below for a hint.

> First, find all $0\le u<2\pi$ such that $\sin u=1,$ then use the periodic nature of the sine function to determine the form of all solutions to the equation.

Once you've found all viable $u,$ you should be able to take it from there.